# Comparing two variable voltages with minimal power consumption

Tags: voltage, circuit-design, low-power, comparator

I'm trying to design a circuit that compares two variable voltages V1 and V2 and fires an interrupt to an MCU when V2 is greater than V1 and at the same time V1 must be at least 4.4 V. The range of V1 is 0-4.9 V and V2 is 0-7 V.

The problem with the current design is that the interrupt is fired all the time even when V1 is 0 V.

Is there a way to achieve this with a TLV3691DCKR nano power comparator and high resistance to keep power consumption low?

[image]

Comment: Yes, and the TLV chip you've chosen should do the trick. Your chip already has very high impedance inputs and push/pull outputs. Your circuit is confusing me though... what's the purpose of the 125 mV reference? Why is one op amp feeding into another? It looks like you have two conditions which both need to be met to trigger the interrupt--to me this looks like two comparators plus a logical AND.

Comment: If VIN is 90% of V2 then when V1>4.4V you will have 0.45*V2 on R1/R5 bridge output, compared with 0.5*V2 so INT will be 2.2V. Same with V1<4.4V : output of first comp will be 0V and 0<0.5*V2 so INT = 2.2V Also, supplying a chip with a variable voltage VIN is not a good idea. Plus if V2>4.4V then the U3 input voltage is higher than VCC which could cause problems. Using @Matt S solution with 2 comparators and a logical gate is the solution you want

Comment: the title says that you want to compare two voltages, but your description states that you want to compare three voltages ... V1, V2 and 4.4 V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to design a circuit that compares two variable voltages V1 and V2 and fires an interrupt to an MCU when V2 is greater than V1 and at the same time V1 must be at least 4.4 V.

In other words, you have two comparisons to make, and need both to be true.

```vhdl
if (V2 > V1 && V1 > 4.4) 
  trigger_interrupt();
```

To me, this means a circuit with two comparators and an AND gate. You've already chosen the TLV3691 and that seems fine, and for the AND you might be able to find a similar low-power device, depending on your design needs.

I note that in your spec,

> V2 is 0-7 V.

You pass V2 through a 50% voltage divider; the comparator will see a maximum of 3.5 V. However, the TLV [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv3691.pdf) tells us that inputs are diode-clamped to the supply rails, and the absolute maximum signal input voltage is `(V+) + 0.5`. You are powering U3 with 2.2 V which means you have an absolute maximum input voltage of 2.7 V. It's not clear to me why you chose 2.2 V.

That voltage divider uses 100 MΩ resistors (presumably, to reduce power losses). The TLV3691, like all amplifiers, has an input bias current (i.e. the current drawn by the input terminals); normally 30-100 pA but up to 20 nA. Worst case, the TLV draws enough current to significantly decrease the input voltage reading; remember that the voltage divider formula is just a rearranged KCL, and therefore only works when there's negligible current leaving the middle node through a different path.

Massive resistances also have an effect on the timing of your circuit. You haven't mentioned timing, and the TLV datasheet doesn't mention input capacitance, but as a rough estimate (assuming pin capacitances in the 10 pF range) a 100 MΩ resistor will delay any signal propagation through your circuit by some several milliseconds (i.e. an eternity to a digital logic chip).

The choices you've made in your design (and your post's title) hint at some significant power constraints -- a nanowatt comparator and some *beefy* voltage-dividing resistors -- but as a result, you've hit upon some snags. If I'm wrong about that implied power constraint, or if it's not as stringent as I think, then your design will be a lot easier.

Nonetheless, I recommend something along the lines of the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUncUl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Starting from the top left:

- the zener / resistor combination clips the V2 input voltage at 5.1 V. This prevents an overvoltage at comparator U1 input; voltages below 5.1 V will be compared like normal, but the voltage at the comparator input will never exceed 5.1 V. Since V1 never exceeds 4.9 V, we don't care how much higher V2 actually goes.
- Choose a value of R1 that minimizes power loss when V2 > 5.1 V, but still allows enough current for the comparator to function. (100 MΩ is almost certainly too high.)
- Comparators U1 and U2 are powered from 5 V, allowing them the headroom to compare signals up to V1<sub>MAX</sub> (=4.9 V). 5 V regulators are common, but comparators are sensitive to power supply noise. See the datasheet (esp. the layout section) for advice on mitigating noise.
- V1 is connected to the negative input of U1 (calculating V2-V1>0) and the positive of U2 (calculating V1-4.4>0).
- I'm assuming you've got a stable 4.4 V reference; if not, you can make a nearly-perfect one with a 1.02 MΩ and a 7.50 MΩ in a voltage divider, at a cost of an extra 500 nA of quiescent current.
- the AND gate will need to have 5 V-tolerant inputs, or you'll need to find some way to attenuate the comparator outputs. You can run them through a voltage divider to bring them down to 3.3 V (1.69 MΩ / 3.30 MΩ maybe?) but, again, that costs power (and you trade lower power for slower switching time).

I hope this helps somewhat. Let me know if you have any more questions.